# How to show a message based on cart total

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to display a message on cart page, based on the cart total amount. 
If total is more than 150 the shipping is free, otherwise shipping is cost.

I tried to do that with simple if statement.

```
{% if cart.total_price > 150 %}
            <small class="excluding_tax"><em>Not free shipping</em</small>
            {% else %}
            <small class="excluding_tax2"><em>Free shipping</em></small>
{% endif %}
```

In fact it keeping showing the first sentence, even when cart total changed.

Comment: Question... Are you using smarty to get the javascript into the html?
Also would you mind trying to *display* `cart.total_price` and what's the typeof `cart.total_price`. my assumption is that either it's a string. Or its a fixed number.

Comment: I'm using liquid. cart.total_price it's a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What cost of products are you testing with?  Shopify stores prices in the currency's smallest denomination (eg: cents), so assuming that your store is set up in a currency that normally uses two decimal places you're testing for a cart total that's 150 cents, or 1.50 ($/£/€/etc) or more.

You probably are intending to check for 150.00 ($/£/€/etc), so changing your comparison to `cart.total_price > 15000` should have the effect you're intending.

Comment: No worries!  From my experience, the prices-are-an-integer-number-of-cents feature catches just about everyone the first time.